# Turtle is moving slow

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I created this program but I don't understand why it takes so long to draw the 2 hills of the heart.

I could reduce the numbers at `my_turtle_cursor.speed(5)` in line 117 and in line 128 as I wanted but there was no change.

When I changed the numbers in `my turtle cursor.speed(1)` on line 142, the speed changed as well.

```
import turtle

my_turtle_cursor = turtle.Turtle()

my_turtle_screen = turtle.Screen()


def pause():
    my_turtle_cursor.speed(2)
    for i in range(100):
        my_turtle_cursor.left(90)


def write_Willst_inside_heart():
    my_turtle_cursor.penup()

    my_turtle_cursor.goto(-240, 15)

    my_turtle_cursor.pencolor("#FFFFFF")

    my_turtle_cursor.write("Willst", font=("Helvetica", 24, "bold"))


def write_du_inside_heart():
    my_turtle_cursor.penup()

    my_turtle_cursor.goto(-140, 15)

    my_turtle_cursor.pencolor("#FFFFFF")

    my_turtle_cursor.write("du", font=("Helvetica", 24, "bold"))


def write_meine_inside_heart():
    my_turtle_cursor.penup()

    my_turtle_cursor.goto(-90, 15)

    my_turtle_cursor.pencolor("#FFFFFF")

    my_turtle_cursor.write("meine", font=("Helvetica", 24, "bold"))


def write_Freundin_inside_heart():
    my_turtle_cursor.penup()

    my_turtle_cursor.goto(10, 15)

    my_turtle_cursor.pencolor("#FFFFFF")

    my_turtle_cursor.write("Freundin", font=("Helvetica", 24, "bold"))


def write_sein_inside_heart():
    my_turtle_cursor.penup()

    my_turtle_cursor.goto(160, 15)

    my_turtle_cursor.pencolor("#FFFFFF")

    my_turtle_cursor.write("sein?", font=("Helvetica", 24, "bold"))


def draw_complete_heart():
    my_turtle_cursor.fillcolor("#FF0000")

    my_turtle_cursor.begin_fill()

    my_turtle_cursor.left(140)
    my_turtle_cursor.forward(294)

    draw_left_curve_of_heart()

    my_turtle_cursor.right(190)

    draw_right_curve_of_heart()

    my_turtle_cursor.forward(294)

    my_turtle_cursor.end_fill()


def draw_left_curve_of_heart():
    my_turtle_cursor.speed(5)  # war eigentlich 50

    for i in range(450):
        my_turtle_cursor.right(0.5)
        my_turtle_cursor.forward(1.2)


def draw_right_curve_of_heart():
    my_turtle_cursor.speed(5)  # war eigentlich 50

    for i in range(450):
        my_turtle_cursor.right(0.5)
        my_turtle_cursor.forward(1.2)


my_turtle_cursor.penup()
my_turtle_cursor.goto(0, -200)
my_turtle_cursor.pendown()

my_turtle_cursor.speed(1)  # war eigentlich 50

draw_complete_heart()

write_Willst_inside_heart()

write_du_inside_heart()

write_meine_inside_heart()

write_Freundin_inside_heart()

write_sein_inside_heart()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: You could set speed to `my_turtle_cursor.speed("fastest")` or just turn off drawing with `turtle.tracer(0)` and `turtle.update()` at the end if you want more control and/or instantaneous drawing. How fast do you want it to go? Changing the speed in one place affects all subsequent code until the next speed setting call. So maybe specify it in whatever function you want to adjust.

Comment: set the speed to zero, which is the fastest.  Also `turtle.tracer(0)` will be nearly instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the performance up, without `tracer()`, by removing the intentional slowdowns (`speed(5)`) and drawing less precisely:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

MESSAGE_FONT = ('Helvetica', 28, 'bold')

def write_inside_heart():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, 15)
    turtle.pencolor('white')
    turtle.write("Willst du meine Freundin sein?", align='center', font=MESSAGE_FONT)

def draw_complete_heart():
    turtle.fillcolor('red')
    turtle.left(140)

    turtle.begin_fill()

    turtle.forward(297.5)
    draw_left_curve_of_heart()

    turtle.left(170)

    draw_right_curve_of_heart()
    turtle.forward(297.5)

    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_left_curve_of_heart():
    for _ in range(90):
        turtle.right(2.5)
        turtle.forward(6)

def draw_right_curve_of_heart():
    for _ in range(90):
        turtle.forward(6)
        turtle.right(2.5)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-200)
turtle.pendown()

draw_complete_heart()
write_inside_heart()

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

We can do better speed-wise, and possibly recapture some precision, by using turtle's `circle()` method with an `extent` argument instead of drawing the arcs ourselves:

```
def draw_complete_heart():
    turtle.fillcolor('red')
    turtle.left(140)

    turtle.begin_fill()

    turtle.forward(288.8)
    turtle.circle(-135, extent=225)

    turtle.left(170)

    turtle.circle(-135, extent=225)
    turtle.forward(288.8)

    turtle.end_fill()
```